# Link to a component in React/Semantic UI with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, i18next

I need a modal to open with onClick, the variable calling the modal  is nested between Translation keys. Here's some of the code. When clicking the link text, I currently have this error message: Cannot read property 'modaleNouvelleOeuvre' of undefined :-/

```
modaleNouvelleOeuvre(ouvert = true) { /*Ouvert means Open*/
this.setState({ modaleOeuvre: ouvert })
}
```

```
{t('flot.split.tableaudebord.vide.indication')}
<a href="#" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.modaleNouvelleOeuvre() }}>
{t('flot.split.tableaudebord.vide.indication-lien')}</a>
```

There's a button elsewhere on the page to open the same modal:

```
<Modal
open={this.state.modaleOeuvre}
onClose={() => { this.modaleNouvelleOeuvre(false); if (this.state.audio) this.state.audio.stop() }}
size="large"
closeIcon
closeOnDimmerClick={false}
>
```

Comment: Can you add more code or code sandbox link? It's hard to tell from this?

Comment: Not sure what would be useful in this case but I added some

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're invoking `this.modaleNouvelleOeuvre()` inside the `<a>`.

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.modaleNouvelleOeuvre}>

modaleNouvelleOeuvre(e) {  
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({ modaleOeuvre: !this.state.ouvert })
}
```

> Note: e or event is implicit.